# Flutter Open Whatsapp and Tel External Link or Launch Apps

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, url-launcher

i've been looking for the solution around the internet and couldn't solve it yet.

Here is the problem:

My apps are running on flutter with webview website which is build with Laravel. The website have button to open the whatsapp link and phone number to call.

So i build webview apps to browse the website and hoping the apps could open the button i mentioned earlier which is Whatsapp and Call button from the laravel website.

[image: The laravel website]

But flutter apps won't let me open or launch whatsapp in webview.

[image]

For final result, i just want the apps open or launch the Whatsapp and Telephone in the phone.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Hi, in your website, does your button's anchor `<a>` have a `target="_blank"` to open links in new windows ?

Comment: Hi, yes do have. Why ?